# Cloud Firestore .getDocuments callback not functioning on Swift5

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, ios13

I am currently building an iOS13 app using Swift5.
The database I'm using is Cloud FireStore. The following link is the image of my current collection.
[image: Image Of Current FireStore Collection]

I am also using FirebaseAuth.

**My goal** : Remove currently logged in user from all of the rooms the user is currently participating in when applicationWillTerminate. Use `.whereField("participants", arrayContains: displayName)` to find all documents(also known as "rooms") and remove the current user's displayName from each participating "rooms"s `participants` array

**Current Status and Concern** : My code is shown as below. When I terminate my app, `print("displayName")` prints to the console, but all of the codes inside of `db.collection("rooms")` seem to be not responsive. `print("Hello World!")` inside of `db.collection("rooms")` callback does not print to the console along with the rest of callback code. I'm not too sure why `db.collection("rooms")` callbacks are not functioning.

```
    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
    
            let displayName = currentUser.displayName!
            
            print("displayName")    // This prints
            
            db.collection("rooms").whereField("participants", arrayContains: displayName)
                .getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
    
                    print("Hello World!") // This does not print, and the code below doesn't seem to respond
                    
                    if let e = error {
                        print (e.localizedDescription)
                    } else {
                        if let snapshotDocuments = querySnapshot?.documents {
                            for doc in snapshotDocuments {
                                let data = doc.data()
                                print(data)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } // db.collection("rooms")
            } else {
                print("No Current User Signed In")  // This does not print
            }
        print ("End of applicationWillTerminate")   // This prints
    }
```

Comment: According to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate?language=objc "Your implementation of this method has approximately five seconds to perform any tasks and return. If the method does not return before time expires, the system may kill the process altogether." Did you time how long your operation takes outside of `applicationWillTerminate` to make sure it meets this requirement?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you so much for letting me know of that. I will try and let you know.